# windows phone 7.x local push notification

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I dont find information about local push notification in Windows Phone 7.x. I mean it is possible, sending push local, without server and internet connection, just at different times - for example, morning, at midnight, or at lunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that locally without an internet connection. Essentially push notifications generally need a source that can make a web request, be it a server or a phone itself (but the phone needs to have a internet access to be able to make the web request).

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/hh221549.aspx for more info. This will answer other questions you might have about this service.